# opening offline sync files from a .CAB file

Tags: extract

OK, I have downloaded from Windows Live Spaces (don't know if this is useful, but might be) a .CAB file containing an Index.XML file and package.cab, package01.cab through to package12.cab.

The index.XML simply has names of all the subsequent package.cab files and their offsets. The first package.cab has a single 26MB XML file which appears to be an OfflineSyncFile definition which I am guessing is the meta data for all the other packageXX.cab files.

Now the question I have is how should i be going about extracting these things and piecing it all back together again.

I have tried WinRAR, which extracts all 800MB for me into unnamed files and randomly named directories. I have also tried the standard extract in Windows Explorer with much the same resusts.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Rob, it's been a while you asked this question and please take a look to what I've found. I hope it's going to help you to fix the issue you are, or were experiencing:

http://www.winvistatips.com/re-offline-file-synchronization-error-t645953.html

Thanks!